# make error on compiling simple-mtpfs

Tags: ubuntu, make, mtp

Attempting install of [simple-mtpfs](https://github.com/phatina/simple-mtpfs) on a ubuntu machine. I believe I've installed all necessary dependencies as listed at the end of this post.
However I am getting while running

```
sudo make
```

as

> make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.

In my working folder I do see `makefile.am` and `makefile.in`

Does this error mean my configure was not run correctly? I see no errors when configure is run however I do see a syntax error

> ../configure: line 4159: syntax error near unexpected token `FUSE,'

```
//download and extract zip
https://github.com/phatina/simple-mtpfs

//need libmtp
$ sudo apt-get install libmtp-dev

//need to install C compiler
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
$ sudo apt-get update

//need to install latest fuse
$ sudo apt-get install libfuse-dev


//need to install autoconf
$ sudo apt install autoconf

$ sudo autoreconf -i

$ mkdir build && cd build
$ ../configure
$ sudo make
$ sudo make install
```

Comment: You need a generated makefile for make to work. After running `./configure`, what is the return status? Check with `echo $?`

Comment: Even more, the docs say `../configure`, not `./configure` (note the extra dot). Please check that you're running the commands exactly as described. The docs also say : "If you got the sources from git repository, first you have to run: `./autogen.sh`"

Comment: yes, running commands exactly as described.  Running ./autogen.sh makes no difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to first run

```
sudo apt-get install pkg-config
```

before running

```
./autogen.sh
```

Comment: `.sh`, not `,sh`